# Is there any way by which we can integrate playwright with karate?. any sample project or gudilines

Tags: karate, playwright

Is there any way by which we can integrate playwright with karate?. any sample project or guidelines available. I 'm trying to integrate playwright with karate so that i can run my tests

created a new maven project for karate implementation

Comment: To be honest the Playwright support is experimental. It will need some level of community contribution.

Comment: @PeterThomas Thankyou for the reply.  Can you provide some basic guidelines for a simple test run (with playwright- karate). Just I need to confirm the possibility of this integration. I 'm finding difficulty in finding packages.